# Show few colums in DataGridView once row click load record in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to create a DataGridview to load few records after user performs a search in database once user clicks on row it should show all records in TextBoxes.

I have more than 20 TextBoxes and few Comboboxes and a DateTimePicker but I just want to show few columns in the DataGridView.

I know how to load data into a DataGridView on form load, but on search or on row click select all DataGridView Column into TextBoxes I am stuck.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893(v=vs.90).aspx

Simplest way above.  Load all data into the datagridview, set visible = false on columns you don't want to display.  You can then access them in the rowchange event.

If it's large data and performance is an issue, you can load only the columns you want into the datagridview, and then look up the other info on row change with a new query.

Comment: @Aaron how i can use a query in rowchange event to show all data in textboxes, end yes its a large database. can you give an example.

Comment: Yeah give me a few to write something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, here is how to change data on row changing in a datagridview.  you will need to alter this to make the actual database calls.  I made a small table for example purposes.  For this to work, make a new winforms application, put a DataGridView on it and 2 textboxes

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable PretendImADataBase;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PretendImADataBase = CreateTestData();
        //this assigns the row enter event to this function.  Each time the row changes,
        //the function is called.  Inside this function, you load your "big data" columns.
        //That way, you only load 2 or 3 columns for all rows, and each time the row changes,
        //you go back out and load all of the details for only that 1 row.
        //Pretty basic way to load data..
        dataGridView1.RowEnter += dataGridView1_RowEnter;
        //initial loading, only 1 or 2 columns of large dataset, to keep loading time fast.
        //primary key, and enough info to identify the full record.            
        dataGridView1.DataSource = CreateDataSource1();
    }        
    private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
    {
        //This is where you would make your database call to load big data.
        var x = sender as DataGridView;
        if (x.DataSource == null) return;
        var id = x[0, e.RowIndex].Value;

        DataRow oRow = (from DataRow row in PretendImADataBase.Rows where (int)row["FK"] == (int)id select row).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!(oRow == null))
        {
            textBox1.Text = oRow[3].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = oRow[4].ToString();
        }
    }
    private DataTable CreateTestData()
    {
        DataTable oDt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn oCol = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
        oDt.Columns.Add(oCol);
        oCol = new DataColumn("FK", typeof(int));
        oDt.Columns.Add(oCol);
        oCol = new DataColumn("Data1", typeof(string));
        oDt.Columns.Add(oCol);
        oCol = new DataColumn("Data2", typeof(string));
        oDt.Columns.Add(oCol);

        DataRow oRow = oDt.NewRow();
        oRow["ID"] = 1;
        oRow["FK"] = 1;
        oRow["Data1"] = "Test Data 1";
        oRow["Data2"] = "Test Data 2";
        oDt.Rows.Add(oRow);
        oRow = oDt.NewRow();
        oRow["ID"] = 2;
        oRow["FK"] = 2;
        oRow["Data1"] = "Test Data 3";
        oRow["Data2"] = "Test Data 4";
        oDt.Rows.Add(oRow);
        return oDt;
    }
    private DataTable CreateDataSource1()
    {
        DataTable oDt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn oCol = new DataColumn("ID",typeof(int));
        oDt.Columns.Add(oCol);
        oCol = new DataColumn("Display", typeof(string));
        oDt.Columns.Add(oCol);

        DataRow oRow = oDt.NewRow();
        oRow["ID"] = 1;
        oRow["Display"] = "Test 1";
        oDt.Rows.Add(oRow);
        oRow = oDt.NewRow();
        oRow["ID"] = 2;
        oRow["Display"] = "Test 2";
        oDt.Rows.Add(oRow);
        return oDt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i figured it out with more simple way. i am loading data into gridview by searching it using textchanged event than in cell click event loading employee id into search text box then loading all details into textboxes once clicking i click Get Data button. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I get what you want but, you are using the datasource of the datagridview to bind the results, right? if so, after you selected the datasourse, you can hide the columns you dont want to show, like this:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = YourDataTable;
// hide the columns you dont want on grid
dgv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
dgv.Columns[2].Visible = false;
dgv.Columns[3].Visible = false;
dgv.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

This way your grid will show only the columns you want, but when the click event triggers you can access the hidden columns to show them on your controls.

Comment: how can i add . Visible = false; in to this txtbox1.Text = dr["id"].ToString();

Comment: @Bukhalifa you want to hide the windows form control?  try txtbox1.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple task.

1. You have to add all the columns in your GridView as the text fields you have on your form.
2. You can set the Visible property of the column to true that you want to show otherwise you can hide by setting this property to false.
3. Now, you will be able to fill the row data to the relevant fields on the form using CellDoubleClick or CellClick or RowDoubleClick or RowClick events.
4. You have to set the property of grid view AutoGenerateColumns to False and the name of each data table column name is to map with grid view columns using DataGridViewProperty.